# AppLovin SDK: NullPointerException (Firebase Crashlytics)

Tags: android, mopub, applovin

I migrated my Android App from MoPub SDK to AppLoving SDK and now Firebase Crashlytics gives me some errors:

[image]

Did anyone have such issues?

Comment: Interestingly enough, their app is running with `minifyEnabled false`. :-)

Comment: @karllindmark well it seems it is about some logic code error in the library, they trying to get length of some string reference when it is null :)